# angular primeng p-confirmdialog - how to replace close icon of dialog panel with google material icon

Tags: angular, primeng, google-material-icons, primeng-dialog

I am working on a requirement where I need to replace the dialog panel's close icon with google material icon.

Find the following screenshot in which I want to replace the close icon with google material icon.

[dialog box screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WYFN.png)

Following code generates dialog with some custom messages.

```
confirm(data, dt): boolean {
    let confirmation = false;
    let message
    if (data.SelfOwner == true) {
      message = 'Delete this Dashboard?'
    }
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: message,
      header: 'Confirm delete'
)}
```

example to add google material icon as follows.

```
<span class="material-icons">
delete
</span>
```

But the dialog box automatically rendered with it's default css & html component like.

[generated code for dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYs9p.png)

Can someone guide me how to override dialog's close icon with google material icon.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so where are you stuck? share some component code related to the close icon

Comment: @sid I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the p-dialog-titlebar-close css class to update the close icon element.

Maybe you must do that change in style.scss file.